# Extract column from file with shell

Tags: shell, ash

I would like to extract column number 8 from the following table using shell (ash):

```
0xd024  2       0       32      20      3       0       1       0       2       1384    1692    -61     27694088
0xd028  0       1       5       11      1       0       46      0       0       301     187     -74     27689154
0xd02c  0       0       35      14      1       0       21      0       0       257     250     -80     27689410
0xd030  1       1       15      13      1       0       38      0       0       176     106     -91     27689666
0xd034  1       1       50      20      1       0       8       0       0       790     283     -71     27689980
0xd038  0       0       0       3       4       0       89      0       0       1633    390     -90     27690291
0xd03c  0       0       8       3       3       0       82      0       0       1837    184     -95     27690603
0xd040  0       0       4       5       1       0       90      0       0       0       148     -97     27690915
0xd064  0       0       36      9       1       0       29      0       0       321     111     -74     27691227
0xd068  0       0       5       14      14      0       40      0       0       8066    2270    -85     27691539
0xd06c  1       1       39      19      1       0       15      0       0       1342    261     -74     27691850
0xd070  0       0       12      11      1       0       53      0       0       203     174     -73     27692162
0xd074  0       0       18      2       1       0       75      0       0       301     277     -94     27692474
```

How can I do that?

Comment: the purpose is to extract the row

Comment: I mean the column number 8

Comment: ok then `awk '{print $8}' file`

Comment: it works , thx @anubhava

Comment: it is possible to extract tow colum: number 2 and number  8 at the same time

Comment: `awk '{print $2, $8}' file`

Answer (score 1):

the following command "awk '{print $8}' file" works fine

Comment: This comment shouldn't not be posted as answer.

Comment: is it possible to extract 2 colums ?